# Is an "inspired by" question accepted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

First of all I will like to know if there is a record of such instance. Some questions may arise from within a previous question or most often bible quotations and little comments to that question. Perhaps to give credit to the one who asked or demand for in-depth answers to that tiny part that strikes me, to what standard should my question with "inspired by the question..." be to avoid closure. The "inspiring" (previous) question may have very little or no answers that fully shed light on where my interest lies. Would it be seen as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

All questions should stand alone on their own merit. It should not be necessary to go back and read through some previous question, answer or comment thread in order to make out what the question is about.

That being said, however the idea sparked in your head, there is no prohibition on forming questions out of whatever material you come across. You just need to do the work of forming it into a complete stand along question that can be answered in it's own right. Being tangentially related to a previous question on this site does not necessarily make it a duplicate.

Comment: @caleb Good to have you especially here as I cannot use my chat privilege. This question is due to the closure on my question on the big deal about God's love... which you were part of the voters. You said I could reopen it if I could focus on a tiny part of it that I need answers on. I'm just about doing that.

Comment: @caleb Will I need to edit the question title to suit the new editted question?

Comment: Hey @Nok! Yes, if you edit into a more focused question dealing with just one angle of that scenario, it would need a new title to reflect that. However I might suggest opening a new question. Most closed questions don't serve any lasting purpose and will eventually be deleted, but that is NOT the case for duplicates. Your question serves a purpose even though it is closed in allowing other people searching for similar wording to yours to find the other question. As such it will not be deleted and will continue to earn you rep. I would be inclined to leave it and ask a fresh question.

Comment: @ Caleb thanks a lot for that suggestion. I was thinking about it too, the loss of attention it may need. I think I would take what you're saying but then I'm bothered. I fear of another possible duplicate. Isn't it becoming increasingly cumbersome as Christianity SE grows to make sure a question is not reposted. For instance I'll have to read lots of questions, under the SIN tag after the title is given before posting?

Comment: @Nok: Don't worry too much about it. If you've searched a little bit looking for questions that might answer what you have on your mind and you have _not_ found anything that directly answers your question, just ask.